# SSRS Subscription using REST API

Tags: web-services, reporting-services, ssrs-2017, ssrs-subscription

Can we create/modify SSRS Subscription using REST API as SQL Server Reporting services 2017 supports REST API calls?

Answer (score 4):

here is an online swagger example they built, but some properties are invalid or missing. Ex: Schedule property is missing and ExtensionSettings.ParameterValues is an array instead of an object

https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/microsoft-rs/SSRS/2.0#/Subscriptions/GetSubscriptions

here is an example of a body message that works for me when posting:

```json
{ "DataQuery": null, "DeliveryExtension": "Report Server Email", "Description": "test3", "EventType": "TimedSubscription", "ExtensionSettings": { "Extension": "Report Server Email", "ParameterValues": [ { "IsValueFieldReference": false, "Name": "TO", "Value": "userName" }, { "IsValueFieldReference": false, "Name": "IncludeReport", "Value": "True" }, { "IsValueFieldReference": false, "Name": "RenderFormat", "Value": "PDF" }, { "IsValueFieldReference": false, "Name": "Subject", "Value": "@ReportName was executed at @ExecutionTime" }, { "IsValueFieldReference": false, "Name": "IncludeLink", "Value": "True" }, { "IsValueFieldReference": false, "Name": "Priority", "Value": "NORMAL" } ] }, "IsActive": true, "IsDataDriven": false, "LastRunTime": null, "LastStatus": "New Subscription", "LocalizedDeliveryExtensionName": "E-Mail", "ModifiedBy": "userName", "ModifiedDate": "2020-09-04T13:45:51.343-05:00", "Owner": "userName", "ParameterValues": [], "Report": "/Folder Name/Report Name", "Schedule": { "Definition": { "EndDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z", "EndDateSpecified": false, "Recurrence": { "DailyRecurrence": { "DaysInterval": 1 }, "MinuteRecurrence": null, "MonthlyDOWRecurrence": null, "MonthlyRecurrence": null, "WeeklyRecurrence": null }, "StartDateTime": "2020-09-04T02:00:00-05:00" }, "ScheduleID": null }, "ScheduleDescription": "At 2:00 AM every day, starting 9/4/2020" }
```